# Using CategoryFilter to search through an array rather than matching a column

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to create a CategoryFilter that will search an array for a value rather than just matching the column.

For example if I have the following DataTable that contains data about t-shirts:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn("string", "ItemName");
data.addColumn("number", "Price");
data.addColumn("string", "Size");
data.addRows([
  // Loop through and add some records
]);
```

I can create a CategoryFilter easily enough to filter on sizes

```
var sizePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  "controlType": "CategoryFilter",
  "containerId": "size-picker",
  "options": {
    "filterColumnLabel": "Size"
  }
});
```

So far this all works great.

Now lets say I want each t-shirt record to contain an array of available colors that the shirt comes in.

So basically I'd like to have something like this for a record

```
[ "Crew T-Shirt", "10", "Large", [ "Blue", "Striped", "White" ]]
```

Then a CategoryFilter has a list of the colors, and when a color is picked the filter searches the array and if it contains the selected color, it's included in the result set.

Now since [DataTable's addColumn()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn) method doesn't support arrays, I'm not sure how to go about this. I can't even find a way to override the filtering methods. Would anything like this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Most people list all the combinations in the DataTable, use a couple of `CategoryFilter`s and bind them all in a `Dashboard`. For example:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Item Name', 'Price', 'Size', 'Color'],
  ['Crew T-Shirt', '10', 'Large', 'Blue'],
  ['Crew T-Shirt', '10', 'Large', 'Striped'],
  // etc...
]);

var sizePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  "controlType": "CategoryFilter",
  "containerId": "size-picker",
  "options": { "filterColumnLabel": "Size" } });
var colorPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'color-picker',  // or whatever....
  'options': { 'filteredColumnLabel': 'Color'} });
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard( DOC.EL_BY_ID('XXX') );
dashboard.bind([sizePicker, colorPicker], [ CHART1, CHART2, etc. ]);
dashboard.draw(dataTable);
```